# Código para generar un "sorteo" tipo MSN Messenger 2009

Tags: javascript, html5, imagen

¿recuerdan MSN Messenger plus!? en 2009 realizo un "sorteo" honestamente no recuerdo cuales fueron los premios, pero la dinámica era fabulosa, consistía en una imagen dividida en pixeles cada uno con un valor donde el usuario ingresaba y daba click en los millones de pixeles, el afortunado y con mucha suerte dando click en uno de los pixeles ganadores generaba una alerta de "ganador" con una pequeña animación y automáticamente solicitaba nombre y correo electrónico para poder ser almacenado y poder reclamar su premio, estoy buscando realizar algo si no igual muy parecido pero en sitio web, aunque pienso que java es el mejor camino, con las nuevas tecnologías, HTML5 tal vez pudiera realizarse esto de una manera mas fácil y dinámica, me gustaría saber si lo recuerdan y si tienen alguna sugerencia de como lograr el objetivo, así como algún código que pueda ser de ayuda! Muchas Gracias!

[image: Banner de inicio al concurso]

Comment: ¿Qué te parece usar un [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_images.asp)? [En esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172115/get-the-mouse-coordinates-when-clicking-on-canvas) hay un ejemplo que recoge los clicks hechos encima de un elemento canvas, que a su vez puede almacenar una imagen. Estos clicks devuelven una posición x e y, o, en definitiva, cada pixel. Para comprobar si el pixel es ganador, deberías utilizar llamadas al servidor, ya que si lo pones en la página HTML o el archivo JavaScript, es posible verlos desde el lado del cliente.

Comment: Me gusta mucho la idea! es muy preciso y se acerca bastante muchas gracias! vamos a darle una revisada!! saludos!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo así, obviamente tienes que conectarlo con el Back para temas de seguridad de tu sorteo, pero ya tienes más de la mitad del camino.

Espero te sirva.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var i = 0, winners = [1, 5, 22, 50, 2, 7, 18], trai = 3, won = false;
  
  for( i; i <= 50;){
    let x = 0,
       tr = '<tr>';
       
      for( x; x <= 50; ){
        tr+='<td id="'+x+'"></td>';
        x++;
      }
    tr+='<tr>';
    
    i++;
    $('.table tbody').append( tr );
  }
  
  $(document).on('click','td',function(){
  if( won ){
    alert('Ya ganaste en otra ocación, Comunicate al 55 44 33 22 11');
  }
  
  else{
      if( trai > 0){
      let value = parseInt( $(this).attr('id') );
    if( winners.indexOf( value ) !== -1){
      alert( 'Ganaste! Comunicate al 55 44 33 22 11' );
      won = true;
    }
    
    else{
      alert(' Lástima margarito, no ganaste nada :(, tienes ' + trai + ' intentos mas');
      trai--;
    }
  }
  
  
  else{
    alert('Ya gastaste todos tus intentos');
  }
  }

  });
});
```

```css
td{
  cursor: pointer;
}

body{
 background: url('http://jsequeiros.com/sites/default/files/imagen-cachorro-comprimir.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero evitamos contestar este tipo de respuestas. De prefrencia que cumplan con **[mcve]**

Comment: Y por eso me pones un -1? La respuesta está bien, estoy aquí para apoyar a mis colegas, no para ponerles el pie. Gracias.

Comment: Yo no vote -1. No es ponerle el pie es seguir las reglas del sitio. Para que las leas **[answer]**

Comment: Lee cómo funciona SO estas preguntas no se responden